# Recursion not returning correct value

Tags: java, recursion

I have a problem with my recursion statement in the helper function. I'm trying to return the cointCount which is the number of coins needed to add up to the amount. I was able to recursively number of coins, but when I return it, it doesn't get the correct value.

```
class Solution {
    public int coinChange(int[] coins, int amount) {
        int ans = helper(coins, amount, 0);
        return ans;
    }
    
    public int helper(int[] coins, int amount, int coinCount) {
        if (amount < 0 ) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (amount == 0) {
            System.out.println(coinCount);
            return coinCount;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {
            helper(coins, amount-coins[i], coinCount+1);
        }
        return coinCount;
    }
}
```

Say if coins was [1,2,5] and amount was 10, then I should return 2 (because I can have two coins of 5).

Comment: I'll give you a hint and that's that the typical solution for this problem doesn't involve calling your recursive function in a loop.

Comment: The problem permits using the same coin multiple times, but I still don't need the loop?

Answer (score -1):

Your function will return whatever coinCount it is given because nothing in your function changes it.

Comment: I see. I'm returning a value but I'm never using the return value for the recursion function. And it will lead to the same return in the end.